# Calling RSV Validation with .click()

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using Benjamin Keen's RSV (Really Simple Validation), however the way Im structuring my site I have the javascript at the bottom of the page which is causing an error with a horrible inline js on the form I'm validating..

currently the form has:

```
onSubmit="return RSV(this, rules);
```

I want to change it to something like this:

```
registerForm.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //alert("fired!");
    return RSV($(this), rules);

});
```

However the console is reporting a Uncaught **ReferenceError: rules is not defined**

I would rather not use inline javascript, has anyone come across this or understand enough to help - anyhelp will be much appreciated.

[Link to examples of the validation code on Benjamin's website](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/experiments/rsv/jquery/?page=5)

This is an example of the rest of the code required to make the plugin work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo_form5").RSV({
      onCompleteHandler: myOnComplete,
      errorFieldClass: "errorFieldDemo5",
      displayType: "display-html",
      errorHTMLItemBullet: "&#8212; ",
            rules: [
                    "required,first_name,Please enter your first name.",
                    "required,last_name,Please enter your last name.",
                    "required,email,Please enter your email address.",
                    "valid_email,email,Please enter a valid email address.",
                    "required,any_integer,Please enter your age.",
                    "digits_only,any_integer,The age field may only contain digits.",
                    "required,marital_status,Please enter your marital status."
]
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Using prevent default doesn't really work as intended here. It may work in some browsers it may also stop the form from submitting altogether so I would omit it. 
    e.preventDefault();

The following does work as you pointed out...

```
$('#btnSubmit').submit(function(){
    return RSV(this, rules);
});
```

...your button in the form needs to be an input field with type submit and the matching id as you have it:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" >
```

I've found some older browser versions, cough IE 8, will occasionaly allow the form to submit twice giving you two new records in the db. To ensure this doesn't happen change your myOnComplete to:

```
function myOnComplete(){
      $(this).find("input[type='image'],input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

I was targeting the form not the submit button, and also using .click() where I should of been using .submit().

the correct code for this is as follows:

```
    $('#btnSubmit').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return RSV(this, rules);
    })
```